# RenPy Images not defining

Tags: renpy

For some reason images in my project do not get defined.

I have a file named `01_Defs.rpy` where all my image and character definitions are placed.
For some reason images defined in it can't be used in other script named `script_schenki.rpy`.
On the contrary characters that I define in it can be used without any problems

## Error that i get

```
I'm sorry, but an uncaught exception occurred.

While loading <renpy.display.im.Image object ('images/mim normal happy.png') at 0x0000000006086e20>:
  File "game/script_schenki.rpy", line 15, in script
    "Test"
  File "renpy/common/000window.rpy", line 114, in _window_auto_callback
    _window_show(auto=True)
  File "renpy/common/000window.rpy", line 69, in _window_show
    renpy.with_statement(trans)
OSError: Couldn't find file 'images/mim normal happy.png'.
```

## What have I tried

I tried renaming files, checking if they are in the same folder, checking if these files are actually being saved by my code editor.

Moving the image definitions to the same file where they are used (from `01_Defs.rpy` to `script_schenki.rpy`) fixes the problem, but it is not the solution I'm searching for.

## What am I searching for

Solution that will allow me to load images in `01_Defs.rpy`.

## Code

`01_Defs.rpy` - https://pastebin.com/T3J3WEuH

`script_schenki.rpy` - https://pastebin.com/7hnFacWD